# How to change ListView representation of data, when using of Model/View in Qt?

Tags: qt, view, model

I'm new to Qt and I want to understand something.
Let's say, that I have a list of strings:

```
QStringList fruits;
fruits << << "Apple" << "Orange" << "Strawberry" << "Mango" << "Blackberry"
```

And I have a model:

```
QStringListModel fruitModel;
fruitModel.setStringList(fruits);
```

This model is connected to a ListView widget:

```
QListView lw;
lw.setModel(&fruitsModel);
lw.show();
```

I got a ListView with a list of fruits:

- Apple
- Orange
- Strawberry
- Mango
- Blackberry

It's good, but what I want is to make this list numbered (for example)

- 1. Apple
- 2. Orange
- 3. Strawberry
- 4. Mango
- 5. Blackberry

What I know is that I can sort or filter these items. But can I change representation of data with a model and without touching an original StringList?

Comment: Do you want the numbers to appear as text in front of the fruit names as part of the cell content or do you want the numbers to appear on the left side as row labels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a proxy model to alter the data to be returned to the view, especially Qt::DisplayRole:

```
class EnumerateProxyModel : public QIdentityProxyModel
{
public:
    explicit EnumerateProxyModel(QObject *parent = 0)
        : QIdentityProxyModel(parent) 
    {
    }

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const {
        if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
            return QStringLiteral("%1. %2").arg(QString::number(index.row() + 1),
                                                QIdentityProxyModel::data(index, Qt::DisplayRole).toString());
        }

        return QIdentityProxyModel::data(index, role);
    }
};
```

Then set it on the view instead of the original model:

```
QStringListModel fruitModel;
...
EnumerateProxyModel enumerateProxy;
enumerateProxy.setSourceModel(&fruitModel);
lw.setModel(&enumerateProxy);
```